# Making a Counter in MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, loops

I am trying to get mysql to do the job by it self, I'm using Navicat Enterprise and my new problem is if i wanted to make a SPECIFIC column to alter everytime i execute the command.
EXAMPLE:

```
    INSERT INTO RESULT ()
VALUES
    (
        '1-10218',
        'FIRST',
        '1-10220', /* I WANT THIS TO ACT AS A VARIABLE, SO IT CHANGES 1 AT A TIME [INCREMENTAL] */
        'SECOND'
    )
```

could i use something like `@NUM += 1` ???
NOTICE that i'm not programming this into anything, so the security or best practices are not in my interest, i just want it to change the value one at a time.
My Desired OUTPUT WOULD BE LIKE THIS:

```
1-10218   FIRST   1-10220   SECOND
1-10218   FIRST   1-10221   SECOND
1-10218   FIRST   1-10222   SECOND
1-10218   FIRST   1-10223   SECOND
1-10218   FIRST   1-10224   SECOND
1-10218   FIRST   1-10225   SECOND
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do inremental values :

```
 SELECT  s.*, 
         @i:=@i+1 AS increnatal
 FROM table_source AS s,
        (SELECT @i:=0) AS inc
```

Exact insert i can provide after showing by You input.

```
INSERT INTO RESULT (COLUMNS) 
SELECT  '1-10218', 'FIRST', CONCAT('1-', @i:=@i+1), 'SECOND'
FROM table_source AS s,
    (SELECT @i:=10219) AS inc
```

Comment: could please be kind enough and give me an example with INSERT?
I'm new in MySQL.
what i got from yours is to define a value like this:
INSERT INTO RESULT () VALUES ('FIRST','1-10218',@i,'SECOND')
but i also have problem with syntax, where i have to define the variable and do i have to make a function or what?

Comment: SELECT  '1-10218', 'FIRST', CONCAT('1-', @i:=@i+1), 'SECOND'
 FROM table_source AS s,
        (SELECT @i:=10219) AS inc

Comment: Oh Perfect:)
can u explain this part ?
AS s, (SELECT @i:=10219) AS inc

Comment: this is where You set start number.

Comment: 1 - in my case "table_source" should be replaces with what? 
2 - so when it stops looping?

Comment: when i change it to RESULT it says `[Err] 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: YES! i finally did it but it turns out that about that counting problem there's not end to it can i use a `WHERE @i < number` ???